# A triangle perspective with many well-known triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle, construct a circle $(O_a)$ touching to $B$-excircle, $C$-excircleand inside the circumcircle at $A_b, A_c, A$ repectively. Define $B_c, B_a$ and $C_a, C_b$ cyclically. Let $A_1B_1C_1$ be the triagle form by $A_bA_c, B_cB_a, C_aC_b$. Then show that $A_1B_1C_1$ and ABC are perspective:

[image]

See [Perspective triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerspectiveTriangles.html)

Comment: Err... what's the question?

Comment: Probably prove the 7 statements?

Comment: Does "perpective with" mean "similar to"?

Comment: I edited the question to clearly.

$ABC$ and $A_1B_1C_1$ are perpective mean $AA_1, BB_1, CC_1$ are concurrent

See [Perpective triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerspectiveTriangles.html)

Comment: @OaiThanhĐào: It's "perSpective", not "perpective".

Comment: @AlexM. I thank to you very much.